# Which makes better sense?

Tags: structure, description, grammar, tenses

Is it correct to say:

> Sign Up to our Newsletter

Or

> Sign Up for our Newsletter

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests to rephrase a single sentence are off-topic for us, as they are unlikely to help anyone else. Please take our tour and see our help center http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic to see what kinds of questions we answer.

Comment: I was aware of the rules, but the 'Thanks!' at the end made me force myself to answer it, haha. @Lauren Ipsum

Comment: I'm really sorry I broke the rules; please don't ban me I wasn't aware of them :( and I'm really grateful Lythric <3

Comment: Andy, no worries; you won't get banned for one off-topic question, particularly if it's your first. :) feel free to poke around and learn all about us! We're a pretty nice bunch. Even to newbies. :)

Comment: How about a moderator just moves this to English where it belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sign Up for Our Newsletter

This is correct because it is grammatically saying: 'if you sign up to this, you will get our newsletter'. So, your signing up *for* the purpose of getting the newsletter.

In English, capitalise everything in titles save: articles (a, the), connectives (but, and) and prepositions (on, at).

I hope this helped.